# how to bash script menu in one row only

Tags: shell-script

I am creating a menu in a script (#!/bin/bash), and it works as I needed:

```
PS3='[ menu ] choose partition tool:'
options=("fdisk" "cfdisk" "continue")
select opt in "${options[@]}"
do
    case $opt in
        "fdisk")
            fdisk /dev/sda
            ;; 
        "cfdisk")
            cfdisk
            ;;
        "continue")
            break
            ;;
        *) echo "invalid option $REPLY"
            ;;
    esac
done
```

this is the result on screen:

```
1) fdisk
2) cfdisk
3) continue
[ menu ] choose partition tool:
```

how can I transform the layout like this (?):

```
[ menu ] choose partition tool (1) fdisk (2) cfdisk (3) continue:
```

in a nutshell, I know that it is enough to write the options in PS3= like this: *PS3='[ menu ] choose partition tool (1) fdisk (2) cfdisk (3) continue:'* but I want to know how not to bring up the options list (up on description).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to write the code for your custom version of `select` yourself. Something like this might work:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
PS3='[ menu ] choose partition tool:'
options=('fdisk' 'cfdisk' 'continue')

while :
do
    printf '%s' "$PS3"
    for ((i = 0; i < ${#options[@]}; i++))
    do
        printf ' (%d) %s' $((i+1)) "${options[i]}"
    done
    read -p ': ' opt

    case "$opt" in
        1|"fdisk")
            fdisk /dev/sda
            ;;
        2|"cfdisk")
            cfdisk
            ;;
        3|"continue")
            break
            ;;
        *) echo "invalid option $opt"
            ;;
    esac
done
```

Comment: exactly wath I need and work, with my current skills (they are limited to simple commands and simple combinations, the rest is copy and paste around the Internet) I would not have known how to build it, but I understood why: select is just an premaded default menu, and if I wanted to change it i would basically have to change the kernel syntax (or something like that). here my script (work in progress): https://github.com/70V07/vmaib.git ─ EDIT: I re-comment why have changed the link due to changed the name of the script, sorry if annoying, not my intention; and ty again.